# How to prevent CSRF attack which is possible with webclient in C# ASP.NET MVC and Web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api, csrf, csrf-protection

I am able to reproduce CSRF attack on my MVC website that uses 
`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` with following steps. And I have a Web Api acting as attacker's environment, and a malicious html page that connects to this web api to retrieve CSRF tokens.

Steps:

1. Valid user is logged into my MVC website.
2. While the session is active, user is tricked into opening a malicious webpage (not website since SameOrigin can be restricted).
3. On this page, an ajax call is made to attacker's Web Api and that application uses WebClient to download content from the MVC website which the user is logged into. By doing this, attacker can get CSRF tokens from the html body as well as from Set-Cookie header. This web api returns these tokens as response to that web page, which then makes some malformed ajax call such as Transfer money or anything related to vulnerable MVC website with cookie and header set in request using javascript.
4. Since the tokens transferred to attacker was different, however both tokens are valid against each other, they are validated automatically and action is executed.

I have done it myself, so how do I protect it in such cases ? Please someone help and explain if I am mistaken somewhere, or provide suggestions if any.

Edit: Only the first page (in my case the login page is CSHTML where I am rendering the token, the rest of UI after login is pure HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: just to be sure - you didn't forget to add the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on the action receiving the data ?

Comment: @Wndrr I can add that only on CSHTML calls, the rest of UI is pure html and javascript. I will update the question with this detail. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I may be wrong since I don't know much about security, (I actually would not be able to run a CSRF attack against my own website) but isn't `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` only useful when you also use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` ? i may have misunderstood the question ...

Comment: @Wndrr The @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is used with that ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute but since my website includes only pages that are in pure HTML, I can't use them so I am reading these form token and passing it as header value and as for the cookie token, it passes anyway. There is no other way to make it work. The website is mix of both.

Comment: Hmmm, okay :-) Sorry then, I can't help :-/